# How to slice/index, easily, multi-dimensional arrays in Numpy/Python?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, slice

I have a numpy array of size (15 x 200 x 3) called rap.
I would like to slice it based on a 2d list such as this one:

```
fragment = [0  93
            7  102
            6  43
           11  167]
```

This is basically the list of the first two indices of the original 3d array, which I want to return.

It gives error when I try to do it this way:

```
rap_sliced = rap[fragment, :]
```

or

```
rap_sliced = rap[list(fragment), :]
rap_sliced = rap[fragment]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the shape of the result?

Comment: You need to provide 2 lists, one for each index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming input:

```py
>>> fragment
[[0, 93], [7, 102], [6, 43], [11, 167]]
>>> fragment=np.array(fragment)
```

this will work:

```py
rap[fragment[:, 0], fragment[:, 1], :]
```

So

```py
numpy_array[X, Y, Z]
```

where `X, Y, Z` could be single value, list (one dimensional), or `:`

Alternatively for `numpy` you can do:

```py
numpy_array[boolean_array]
```

where `numpy_array.shape=boolean_array.shape` and `boolean_array` essentially provides you `True/False`, whether return or not value with given coordinates from `numpy_array`